# Nodejs Error : " User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile "

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I have a Nodejs code that runs queries on the Google Analytics API, I'm using the **googleapis** library for authentication and getting data.

But my problem occurs when I try to send queries to retrieve "page views" for example, but in the end, I get an error.
therefore, I had added the **client_email** for my service account to the Google Analytics.

## NodeJS Code :

```
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(keys.client_id, null, keys.private_key, scopes)


async function getData() {
  const response = await jwt.authorize()
  const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    'auth': jwt,
    'ids': 'ga:146850375',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
  }).then( (res) => console.log(res) )
  .catch( (e) => console.error(e) )


  console.dir(result)
}

getData()
```

## Results :

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWJZm.png

Answer (score 0):

## Solution :

Actually, the Account Id (under Admin -> Account -> Account Settings) is not the correct number to use as your Profile Id. You have to use the specific View Id that you want to analyse. These may be the same **(sometimes)**, but they may also be different, as it is my case.